# How can I get user (self) rated movies/series data from IMDB (mostly python)?

Tags: python, api, web-scraping, imdb, imdbpy

I want to retrieve reviews that I have given to movies/series on IMDB app/website under my account.

Does IMDB expose any such API?

I tried accessing the URL mentioned in the screenshot. But looks like I need the token?

How to get IMDB token?

I went through https://github.com/alberanid/imdbpy but looks like there are no such API's to get user reviewed data.

[image: 1]

Can anyone please guide me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a different way altogether and it worked,

```
import requests
import browsercookie
import bs4
url = 'https://www.imdb.com/user/ur<user_id>/ratings?ref_=nv_usr_rt_4'
cj = browsercookie.chrome()
res = requests.get(url, cookies=cj)
res.raise_for_status()
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
```

Comment: Just login to your account from google chrome browser to IMDB, before running this code. And update the userid field with your user ID (its usually a 8 digit integer).

Comment: Yeah, but imdb does not expose API's to get user given ratings, if so please do let me know...

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you are looking for:
http://www.omdbapi.com
IMDB api.

Comment: Thanks for providing the info. But I found another way out. I've pasted the answer. Have a great day.

Comment: I don't see "User API" on that site, so this is not valid answer.